# If $P_n=1+\cos 2^{n-1} x -\sin 2^{n-1} x $ and $Q_n=1+\tan 2^{n-1} x $

Tags: trigonometry

> satisfies $(P_1Q_0)(P_2Q_1).....(P_nQ_{n-1})=1$ then prove that $x$ cannot be $\frac{\pi}{31}$

Subsisting the value 
$$(1+\sin x +\cos x)(1+\tan \frac x2)(1+\sin 2x +\cos 2x)(1+\tan x).....=1$$

I can’t really understand what’s going on here. Can I get a hint?

Comment: Is $P_{n} = 1 + \cos{2^{n-1}x} - \sin{2^{n-1}x}$ or $P_{n} = 1 + \cos{2^{n-1}x} + \sin{2^{n-1}x}$? It seems you have changed the sign of the $\mathrm{sin}$ term between defining $P_{n}$ and substituting into the result